# Flutter - Rendering a custom symbol based fonts

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, custom-font

I am trying to render a custom font made up of symbols, the [Phoenician alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet) to be exact, I have the font file '.ttf', in my pubspec.yaml I added the font as I would normally do when I am about to add a custom font:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Phoenician
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Phoenician.ttf
```

When I tried to test the font out it didn't render and instead showed regular latin characters.

```
Text(test_str, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Phoenician'),
```

I made sure of the font's metadata, it works just fine, I even installed it on my computer.

How exactly can I use this level of customized fonts with flutter?

PS: I am running MacOS and testing on an iPhone 11 simulator

UPDATE:
Those symbols **DO NOT** exist in the table of characters.

Comment: Have you tried to cold restart your app (close debugging session and then re-debug it again)?

Comment: @hisam Yes, I went through that!

Comment: Can you provide the `Phoenician.ttf` file so I can try it on my own?

Comment: @hisam here's a WeTransfer link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c50a85eaf38c8bf716506c62878cace820200729143810/045a16

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using a font with a non-standard encoding? Any relatively recent operating system (MacOS, iOS, Windows, Android) will have fonts that support Unicode-encoded Phoenician characters. If you go to the following link and can see glyphs for Phoenician characters in the table, then your system has font support.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet#Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried the font on my own, It works really fine:

[image: Hello World]

I think the problem is inside the `Phoenician.ttf` file.

Why? See image below:

[image]

As you can see, not all of the letters are "translated" into the Phoenician alphabet
The components that are not "translated" are:

> a, e, f, i, j, o, t, u, v, Capitalized Letters (except T), Numbers, etc.

So, I decided to try the capitalized letter, and then the result is:
[image: HELLO WORLD]

So if you want to use this font, make sure to not use the capitalized letter, number, etc.